# PowerPivot to list data values instead of summarising

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Just starting with MS PowerPivot.  I am trying to create a pivot showing the list of responses to questions in a survey, but am falling over where the powerpivot wants a 'Summarize by' value for the pivoted responses.

In a sql query to return these data I would use max(AnswerComment) (as there will only be one answer per respondent per question). However, when I select Max as the Summarize by values, PowerPivot returns:  ERROR - CALCULATION ABORTED: Calculation error in measure 'Answer'[Maximum of AnswerComment]' and then explains that only numbers or dates (and not Strings) can be 'MAX'ed.

Is there a way of listing pivoted data (rather than performing a summary calculation on it)?  If not, is there a summary function that PowerPivot accepts for string types?

thx
mcalex

Answer (score 0):

By definition, PowerPivot doesn't let you list text values out. The way to workaround this is to place the column onto a row and then make sure you have another measure that includes all values of that column (traditionally dimension).

Saying this, a common approach is to build a Power View report on top of your PowerPivot workbook. This will allow you to list the values.